Can a criminal litigator introduce new evidence if it is pursuant to the veracity of a witness?
Obviously there are limits to how much evidence can be presented in court case and an attorney cannot anticipate every possible shred of evidence that he might need.
For example, let's imagine that in a criminal trial the prosecution presents a witness and asks the witness "Do you know so-and-so?" and the witness answers "No, I never met him." and this strengthens the prosecution's case and surprises the defense. Several people come forward and send phone photos to the defense attorney showing the witness with so-and-so on multiple occasions in social venues, so it appears from the photos that the witness was clearly lying when the witness said they did not know so-and-so. Can the defense then petition the court to admit this new evidence on the grounds that it proves the witness is lying or unreliable?

The defense doesn't need to. Unlike the prosecution in a criminal case that has to disclose basically everything before trial, the duty of the defense in a criminal case to disclose fact witnesses or exhibits to be used at trial in advance is minimal. Since the prosecution goes first, so the defense can simply offer these witnesses or exhibits in their case-in-chief. If the false statement that was unexpected came at the very end of the prosecution's case, the defense could ask for a day or two delay in the timing of the defense presentation of the case to get the witness or exhibits to the court before a verdict is entered.
If a criminal defendant's witness does this, the prosecution can obtain leave to present impeachment evidence in a rebuttal case after the close of the defense's case-in-chief.
In a civil case, the requirement to disclose witnesses and exhibits in advance generally does not apply to impeachment or rebuttal evidence (impeachment evidence is a fancy way to say evidence tending to show someone is lying). But in a civil case, if the party that didn't disclose the evidence had it all along and failed to produce it when required in the discovery and disclosure process, it could be barred as a sanction for not making timely disclosure of the evidence anyway.
Impeachment evidence can generally only be presented after a verdict in either a civil or a criminal case, in a post-verdict motion for a new trial, if it was only discovered after the verdict was entered.

Ok, so the basic takeaway here is that de novo evidence can be submitted to support a rebuttal, is that right?

@Cicero Impeachment and rebuttal evidence is usually admissible even if not anticipated in an initial disclosure of trial evidence, unless there was misconduct related to that evidence by the party seeking to offer it in the pre-trial phase of a case.

In the last sentence, I think the "only" in "can generally only" is either not necessary or should be "also", shouldn't it?

@jcaron The use of the word "only" there is intended. You can consider new evidence only if (1) it is in a post-trial motion, and (2) the evidence was newly discovered after the trial. There are actually also some additional unstated conditions for bringing such a motion, so stating it permissively without "only" would be incorrect. It is generally allowed, it is allowed only if certain conditions are met, two of which are stated and others of which are not stated.
